# c++ Combining Vectors if they Share a Number

Tags: c++, vector

So I have 13 different vectors that have a set of numbers within them. I want to combine the vectors that share numbers, and remove the duplicates. 
Example: If I combine set 0 and 1 I don't want there to be two 2's.

The manner in which they are sorted is how they would always be sorted, so the number 2 won't appear after set two, but can show up before it. The numbers are ordered, etc.

I'm confused how I would go about this.

```
The sets: 
Set 0: [0,2]
Set 1: [1,2,5]
Set 2: [2]
Set 3: [3,4]
Set 4: [4]
Set 5: [5]
Set 6: [6,7,8]
Set 7: [7,9]
Set 8: [8,9]
Set 9: [9]
Set 10: [10, 11]
Set 11: [11, 12]
Set 12: [12]
```

Comment: Check [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) and [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: Thank you, the combination of intersection and union worked for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Outside your method, in main scope
bool contains(std::vector<int> vec, int val) {
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) if(vec[i] == val) return true;
    return false;
}
// Inside your method
std::vector<int> glued;
for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++) { if(!contains(glued, vector1[i])) glued.push_back(vector1[i]); }
// Repeat for all vectors
```

This method is unefficient but I don't know any better.

Answer (score 0):

Use an stl::set container. For each of your arrays, add their values to the stl::set. The set container guarantees that there will only be one instance of a number. When done, convert the set back to a vector if necessary.